# onEnterAnimationComplete() is not called after an Activity Transaction

Tags: android, android-activity, android-transitions

I have two Activities with a single shared object, an `ImageView`. Both activities are subclasses of `AppCompatActivity` and they share the same Theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/transition_slide</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/transition_slide</item>
    <!-- specify shared element transitions -->
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
        @transition/obj_transition</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
        @transition/obj_transition</item>
</style>
```

Activity A calls Activity B in the following way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat
    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ActivityA.this, view, "common_tag");
ActivityCompat
    .startActivityForResult(ActivityA.this, intent, ACT_B_TAG, options.toBundle());
```

On Activity B, I want to start a simple wobbling animation on the same shared ImageView. If I start the animation on the `onCreate` method, the result is quite ugly because it starts *before* the end of the activity transition. So I overwrite the `onEnterAnimationComplete()` method in Activity B:

```
@Override
public void onEnterAnimationComplete() {
    Log.d(TAG, "ANIMATION COMPLETE");
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.wobble);
    findViewById(R.id.SharedView).startAnimation(anim);
}
```

The problem is, nothing happens. The activity and shared element transitions play, but when they end the other animation won't start. Checking the logcat output I see that the method is not even called. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround for that. You can postpone the Activity enter transition, add a preDraw listener to your image (or whatever, it's up to you), setup your animations, and then start the postponed enter transition.

```
postponeEnterTransition();  //  wait until all animations are set up
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);  //  only run once
                enterAnimation();  //  your animations here
                startPostponedEnterTransition();  //  all animations are ran

                return true;
            }
        });
```

I don't know if onEnterAnimationComplete() not getting called is intended behaviour, but if it is then this is a big oversight from the framework team.

Comment: this seems to be a relevant SO question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488410/onenteranimationcomplete-not-called-api-21

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code and it's working perfectly.

Add a button to MainActivity to navigate to ActivityB.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Override Animation of ActivityB to understand properly

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.still);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.still, R.anim.slide_out_down);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.still, R.anim.slide_out_down);
}

@Override
public void onEnterAnimationComplete() {
    super.onEnterAnimationComplete();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Animation Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_clockwise);
    textView.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

slide_in_up.xml

```
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="3000" />
```

slide_out_down.xml

```
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="3000" />
```

still.xml

```
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="3000" />
```

rotate_clockwise.xml

```
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="180"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="3000"/>
```

[image]